# Waterproofing microusb connection

Tags: usb, waterproof

I have a small plastic-bodied soundlevel meter which is entirely sealed with exception to a microUSB port that is used for both data and power. Despite the fact a microUSB connection is not ideal for the application, the meter is being deployed in outdoor environments (preciptation, dust, and UV) in Ontario, Canada, and is expected to function for months at a time.

There have been repeated issues with dropped USB connections during rain events.

What are the best options for protecting this connection?

For this application the USB cable does not need to be removable. The meter has always been deployed with the USB port facing downwards so that the minimum water is incident on the connection.

Non-conductive silicone-base sealant applied around the plug/port interface has been tried - it works perfectly in controlled testing and has improved reliability in the field but failure rates are unacceptably high (~33% in the last rainstorm). It seems the seal is delicate and moderately rough handling that's inevitable during deployment is causing the seal to open. I'm hopeful there's a more rugged option.

At present, Plasti-dip is the next option that will be investigated.

[image: PXL-20230615-125245411.jpg]

Comment: Do you have a image of meter in question, so we can see how the connection looks? This would help IMO to come up with possible solutions.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent added photo

Comment: You can build an enclosure to protect the unit. The port is round, so that would be easy to seal with a gasket and a felt cover.

Comment: @LiorBilia I agree, but that requires some work to be done.

Comment: @davegravy If the cable is not frequently unplugged, I would recommend applying a generous amount of plastic or epoxy sealing. If needed, you can always unplug the other end of the cable to move the unit. This solution is simple, inexpensive, and reliable.

Comment: Try testing it in a rain storm after the device has been left out in the sun for an hour. Temperature changes with water testing are rarely combined but can pull water through seals by changing air pressures by temperature